# How do I change directory to home directory in Script? (bash)

Tags: linux, bash

Hi this is my first time writing bash and I'm trying to practice creating a bash script and am attempting to do the following:

- Using absolute path the script changes directory to your home directory.
- Next it verifies whether a subdirectory called project exists. If it does not exist it creates that directory.
- Next it changes directory moving into the project subdirectory using relative path.

I'm already stuck on the first step:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd
if [ -d ./project ]
    then 
        echo hi it exists!
    else
        echo it doesn't exist!
cd project/
```

I would appreciate if someone could help! thank you so much!

Comment: Do you want the script to leave the directory changed after it exits? Because you can't do that at all, which makes this entire thing moot.

Comment: If you expect to call the script and have it leave you in the target directory when it exits, then you have to source it. `.   scriptName` runs it in your current context instead of a subshell. Was that what you meant to do?

Answer (score 0):

cd by itself changes the current working directory to the home directory. 
See [man cd](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/cdh.html) for other uses of this command.

Comment: Since the OP is already doing that (calling `cd` by itself with no arguments -- on the second line of their script, immediately after the shebang), telling them to do what they're already doing clearly isn't an answer or solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `$HOME` environment variable. Bash also recognizes a tilde (`~`) as home.

Comment: This is true, but fixing that specific, narrow issue won't enable the OP to write a script that changes their shell's (that is, the calling shell's) directory.

Comment: And the OP *is* already running `cd` with no arguments at the top of their script (first line after the shebang), which *does* already change to the home directory just as effectively as `cd "$HOME"` or `cd ~` does.